# WebClient - get response body on error status code

Tags: c#, webclient, bad-request

I'm looking essentially for the same thing asked here: 
[Any way to access response body using WebClient when the server returns an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381576/any-way-to-access-response-body-using-webclient-when-the-server-returns-an-error)

But no answers have been provided so far.

The server returns a "400 bad request" status, but with a detailed error explanation as response body.

Any ideas on accessing that data with .NET WebClient? It just throws an exception when server returns an error status code.

Comment: This other question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036491/get-webclient-errors-as-string

Comment: And this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828843/c-sharp-webexception-how-to-get-whole-response-with-a-body

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You cant get it from the webclient however on your WebException you can access the Response Object cast that into a HttpWebResponse object and you will be able to access the entire response object.

Please see the [WebException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response.aspx) class definition for more information.

Below is an example from MSDN (added reading the content of the web response for clarity)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try {
            // Create a web request for an invalid site. Substitute the "invalid site" strong in the Create call with a invalid name.
            HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("invalid URL");

            // Get the associated response for the above request.
            HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse) myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            myHttpWebResponse.Close();
        }
        catch(WebException e) {
            Console.WriteLine("This program is expected to throw WebException on successful run."+
                              "\n\nException Message :" + e.Message);
            if(e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError) {
                Console.WriteLine("Status Code : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode);
                Console.WriteLine("Status Description : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription);
                using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Content: {0}", r.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it is using HttpWebRequest but it is the same for WebClient as ALL the method can return a WebException

Answer (score 26):

You can retrieve the response content like this:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    try
    {
        string data = client.DownloadString(
            "http://your-url.com");
        // successful...
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        // failed...
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(
            ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string responseContent = r.ReadToEnd();
            // ... do whatever ...
        }
    }
}
```

Tested: on .Net 4.5.2

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it shows how to get the response *body*.

Comment: Excellent! Works as expected - thank you