# WebClient UploadString get header and body when receive 400 bad request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webclient

I'm making an API call using WebClient.UploadString(). It throws an exception since it's a bad request. I cannot find more information in the exception object or the webclient object itself. But if I use Fiddler to listen to the request, it's giving me all details of the headers and body information, so I know exactly the reason. Is there a way to retrieve these info from UploadString()? or should I use some other method like HttpRequest to get the detail? Thanks!

Comment: solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15347388/4983201. catch `WebException`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() Method from System.Net namespace.

**You can find an example in the official msdn doc:** 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

**Also:** You can capture exception (from try-catch of the Request of UploadString) and get the exception stack by rethrowing the exception if you get any additional errors.

```
catch (Exception ex) { String.Format("Error occurred {0} - {1}",ex.Message,ex.ToString()); throw; }
```

You need to log the exception first before you re-throw it to get the according info. If you don't use logging you don't need to re-throw.

Note: You can also view site requests and headers sent using the chrome://net-internals chrome page at the "events" menu.